# Where to find risk report/models for treasury spreads trading?

Tags: interest-rates, risk-management, treasuries

I trade a lot of treasury curves, so say I have a portfolio of treasury cash and futures products (longs and shorts). How do I find the portfolio DV01 risk and curve risk? I couldn't find anything that could help me get started online. If anyone has any resources please help.

Answer (score 0):

CME has DV01s on their website, I think only for futures.  Beyond that you'll need a data provider such as bloomberg, reuters, or subscribe to barclays live.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate DV01 and curve risk you should be able to calculate price from yield first. You could probably take a look at QuantLib - it should able to price a bond from yield. Once you can do that, you can do whatever risk calculations you want. For example, to calculate DV01 you would change yield by 1 basis point and then reprice it.

Comment: What's the industry standard approach to calculating curve risk? That's what I'm stuck on...

Comment: Yield curve risk is a risk of loss arising from a change in the shape of the yield curve. You can consider scenarios of the change in the shape of the yield curve: steepening/flattering; and assume that the worst case scenario would be your curve risk.